# Can't get access to a model element that is connected with a Left Outer Join

Tags: html, vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2017

I'm short on experience with this one.   I think I have the LINQ statement setup correctly to get data from several tables including one that I need to Left Outer Join to.  But I can't get the HTML.DISPLAYFOR statement to see any element in the Model joined with the left Outer Join. (this is VB.net within Visual Studio 2017)  I've looked all over the web and even through the StackOverflow forums.  What I've found is either in C# (which I am slowly learning), or the syntax is too old to work on my system.  An nowhere have I found anyone trying to use the Displayfor function to display field pulled from SQl server using a left outer join.  Help?

MemberApointments Model:

```
Partial Public Class MemberAppointment
    Public Property AppointmentID As Integer
    Public Property MemberEventID As Integer
    Public Property HospitalID As Integer
    Public Property ActualHospitalID As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Overridable Property Hospital As Hospital
```

Hospitals Model:

```
Partial Public Class Hospital
    Public Property HospitalID As Integer
    Public Property HospitalShortName As String
    Public Overridable Property MemberAppointments As ICollection(Of MemberAppointment) = New HashSet(Of MemberAppointment)
```

Controller:

this is the original coding:

```
Public Function Index(id As Integer?, Optional ByVal page As Integer = 0) As ActionResult
        Dim ptsdAppt As IEnumerable(Of MemberAppointment) _
        = From s In db.MemberAppointments Where s.AppointmentID = id
          Group Join ah In db.Hospitals On s.ActualHospitalID Equals ah.HospitalID Into Group
          From ah In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
          Select s
```

Based on a @Cais Jard comment I tried this:

```
Dim ptsdAppt = From m In db.Members Where m.MemberID = id
                           Join l In db.EventHistories On l.MemberID Equals m.MemberID
                           Join s In db.MemberAppointments On l.MemberEventID Equals s.MemberEventID
                           Group Join ah In db.Hospitals On s.ActualHospitalID Equals ah.HospitalID Into acthos = Group
                           From ah2 In acthos.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           Select New With {.Members = m,
                               .EventHistories = l,
                               .MemberAppointments = s,
                               .ActualHospital = ah2
                               }
           Return View(ptsdAppt)
        End Function
```

Third try:
I'm changing someone else's OLD code that looks like this.  Because of the foreign Key on the HospitalID fields, I can easily get the HospitalShortName if it exists:

```
Dim ptsdAppt As IEnumerable(Of MemberAppointment) = From s In db.MemberAppointments
     Join l In db.EventHistories On l.MemberEventID Equals s.MemberEventID
     Join m In db.Members On l.MemberID Equals m.MemberID
     Where m.MemberID = id
     Select s
```

I  have experience in SQL, but not in LINQ.  In the Member Appointment table, there are 2 hospitalID fields (HospitalID and ActualHospitalID) and I need the associated ShortName associated with each from the Hospital table, if they (independently) exist.  If i were to use SQL, I would code it like this:

```
Select 
    s.HospitalID,
    h.HospitalShortName,
    s.ActualHospitalID,
    sh.HospitalShortName
From members as m
    join EventHistory As l 
        on l.MemberID = m.MemberID
    join MemberAppointments as s 
        on l.MemberEventID = s.MemberEventID
    left outer join Hospitals As h 
        on s.HospitalID = h.HospitalID 
    left outer join Hospitals As sh 
        on s.ActualHospitalID = sh.HospitalID 
Where m.SSN = '1'
```

Index view:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of PtdrWeb.MemberAppointment)

@For Each item In Model
    Dim currentItem = item
        <div Class="four columns">
@*because there is a foreign key on the MemberAppointment table to the Hospital table using the HospitalID in both tables, this always gives me the right values *@
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.HospitalID)
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Hospital.HospitalShortName)
        </div>
        <div Class="four columns">
@*on this one, I need the HospitalShortname where the MemberAppointment table is connect to the Hospital table with the ActualHospitalID=HospitalID, what I'm getting the the HospitalShortName associated with the MemberAppointment.HospitalID field.*@
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) (currentItem.ActualHospitalID))
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) (currentItem.Hospital.HospitalShortName))
        </div>
Next
```

Over the past week, I've use a hundred different combinations of the select statement... it either throws and error (something is null) or it doesn't throw an error... but in every case, I can't get the right HospitalShortName in the second case.

Either the LINQ statement is wrong, or I should use something else besides the Displayfor function... I'm at a loss.

Comment: When you find C# you can convert it to VB using something like https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/ - does a reasonable job. Linq (query syntax) should be nearly identical

Comment: thanks for the link... that will help with the other issues I'm researching at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG.  There's a week I'll never get back. In my previous programming experience, you only changed programming, you didn't change the database.
That was a realm of the Database Administrator.  I've been focusing on trying to get the Select statement to work, it never occurred to me to change the database.  Thank you @Caius Jard for the hint.

I changed the LINQ back to the original select statement:

```
    Dim ptsdAppt As IEnumerable(Of MemberAppointment) _
        = From s In db.MemberAppointments
          Join l In db.EventHistories On l.MemberEventID Equals s.MemberEventID
          Join m In db.Members On l.MemberID Equals m.MemberID
          Where m.MemberID = id
          Select s
```

then change the Member Appointment Model to give me another connection to the Hospital Table:

```
Public Overridable Property ActualHospital As Hospital
```

And added a foreign key to the MemberAppointment table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MemberAppointments
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ActualHospital_Hospitals FOREIGN KEY (ActualHospitalID)
      REFERENCES dbo.Hospitals (HospitalID)
```

then I changed the HTML.DISPLAYFOR statement to use the new connection:

```
    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) (currentItem.ActualHospital.HospitalShortName))
```

after refreshing the Model diagram in VS 2017 and fixing the foreignkey to match what actually was in the database... the DisplayFor statement suddenly started producing the data I was looking for.

Comment: It seems that your problem has been solved, so please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite understand why you're taking this approach; I think I'd just key ActualHospital to the Hospital table and let EF make a nav property that will either be a Hospital or Nothing (FKs can be null at the child end) but here is what I think you're trying to do:

#### Setup some sample data, nothing to do with your query

```
    'some demo fluff
    Dim hs As New List(Of Hospital) From {
        New Hospital With {.HospitalID = 1, .HospitalShortName = "New York"},
        New Hospital With {.HospitalID = 2, .HospitalShortName = "Chicago"}
    }

    Dim mas As New List(Of MemberAppointment) From {
        New MemberAppointment With {.ActualHospitalID = 1, .AppointmentID = 1, .MemberEventID = 1},
        New MemberAppointment With {.ActualHospitalID = 1, .AppointmentID = 1, .MemberEventID = 2},
        New MemberAppointment With {.ActualHospitalID = 1, .AppointmentID = 2},
        New MemberAppointment With {.ActualHospitalID = 2, .AppointmentID = 1},
        New MemberAppointment With {.ActualHospitalID = 3, .AppointmentID = 1},
        New MemberAppointment With {.ActualHospitalID = Nothing, .AppointmentID = 1}
    }
```

#### A query to do your join

```
    'the nuts and bolts
    Dim ptsdAppt = From ma In mas Where ma.AppointmentID = 1
                   Group Join h In hs On ma.ActualHospitalID Equals h.HospitalID Into g = Group
                   From gg In g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   Select New With {
                      .MemberAppointment = ma,
                      .ActualHospital = gg
                  }
```

The output from this is a list of objects that have a MemberAppointment property and an ActualHospital proerty that is variably a Hospital or Nothing

I recommend you don't bother using As to force a type on your queries; they'll be inferred by the compiler and it makes it a lot easier to use the result

Comment: thank you, @Caius Jard, but the problem with doing the list method is that the query has 3 other tables that I didn't identify and I can't hardcode all the values into the list. Everything I've searched that gave me that method, did exactly what you did... but I need to be able to join directly to the table.

Comment: my second attempt gave me a Warning on the Compile:  
Analyzer driver threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' with message 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'. 
 and an error on the run: [InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_8`4[PtdrWeb.Member,PtdrWeb.EventHistory,PtdrWeb.MemberAppointment,PtdrWeb.Hospital]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PtdrWeb.MemberAppointment]'.]

Comment: The lists are nothing to do with the answer, they're just me making up some data to prove the query. It was literally just so you could copy, paste, run, see if the query produced something usable for you, then you can wire your own collections into it in place of the lists

Comment: "It blew up" lacks detail. You haven't really made a clear statement of the data you have, what it looks like, or what you want it to look like when you're done querying. Are you doing these joins because you haven't made any codes/designs(fk/relationships in the db) that tells EF how these things relate?

Comment: In other words I just don't understand why you don't tell EF how the graph of objects looks then tell it to start worth one table X and load related tables Y and Z then you can just pull data using the navigation props eg `Dim mem = db.Members.Include(Function(m) m.MemberAppointments).FirstOrDefault(Function(m) m.MemberId = 1)` - this gives mem withba collection of mem.MemberAppointments

Comment: I posted the error from when it blew up on the second attempt.   I'm learning EF the hard way so I don't understand why what I am doing doesn't work when (to me) it looks just like what I have been finding during my searches.  I updated the question to include what the actual original LINQ code looks like and what a SQL statement would look like if i had to code it to get what I wanted.